# django-admin startapp v/s python manage.py startapp

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps, django-admin-actions

What is the difference between django-admin startapp and python manage.py startapp? They both create apps and the files are also same so what's the difference between these two?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, if I am creating an app using python manage.py startapp <app-name> , django is detecting the changes in models, but if I create the same app using django-admin startapp <app-name> Django is not detecting the changes in models and displays no changes detected, can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `manage.py` is meant for the project and comes preconfigured with project-settings.